# Database connection by connection string returns null

Tags: c#, sql

I try a connection between a database using the connection string , who is in a app.config. But the problem is that the variable adapter returns null and so the desired data is not read. I find no error in the code .

```
DataTable ds;

string con = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnect"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select a.aaa, m.bbb, m.ccc m.ddd From lst_mdmel_lis_tab m with (nolock) inner join lst_absae_tab a with (nolock) on a.id = m.id where m.bbb >= 30 and m.fff= 35 order by a.aaa", conn);

    ds = new DataTable(" ");
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds; 
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the values of "con" and when you run the sql manually how many records do you get?

Comment: yes i checked the values of con there are right. What dou you mean with the other question?

Comment: It is literally impossible for that `adapter` variable to be `null`. A type constructor either throws an exception or creates an object.  You need to look again and find out exactly what is really happening.

Comment: @myworld exactly as it sounds, what happens when you run the sql against your data manually, eg not through that code, how many records do you get

Comment: i get about 7000 records.

Answer (score 0):

```
where m.bbb>= '30' and m.fff= '35'
```

`>=` is a comparison operator for numerical values. Therefore, if m.bbb is a numerical value along with m.fff then the correct syntax would be

```
where m.bbb >= 30 and m.fff= 35
```

Comment: yes sorry it was a typing error the code looks exactly like this

Comment: hmmm, you should update the question then to show the code you are using. Also why are you using  `new DataTable(" ")` why not just use `new DataTable()`?

Comment: it was only a test with new DataTable() it also not work